# How to get a mail in response, of the form submission by the User In Strapi

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I am new to Strapi and I want to create functionality, when a user submits form (from the frontend made in React js), in response to it the User will get a mail of form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[to send email in response of the type of request made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Niu5.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this docs: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/plugins/email
Example:

```js
 // This code example can be used in a controller or a service path: ./src/api/{api name}/controllers/{api name}.js or ./src/api/{api name}/services/{api name}.js
      await strapi.plugins['email'].services.email.send({
        to: 'valid email address',
        from: 'your verified email address', //e.g. single sender verification in SendGrid
        cc: 'valid email address',
        bcc: 'valid email address',
        replyTo: 'valid email address',
        subject: 'The Strapi Email plugin worked successfully',
        text: 'Hello world!',
        html: 'Hello world!',
      }),
```